# how to make kotlin interface property with default value to be used in java code

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-interop

Using kotlin 1.6.21, and java 11.
Having a kotlin interface which has property with default value. How to make use it in java code?

```
interface ISomeKInterface {
   val flag: Int
       get() = return 1

   fun onProc(data: String) {
       if (flag == 1) {
          // do something_1
       } else if (flag == 2) {
          // do something_2
       } else {
          // do the other
       }
   }
}
```

in kotlin it could do

```
object : ISomeKInterface {
    override val flag: Int = 2
    override fun onProc(data: String) {
       if (flag == 1) {
          // do something_1
       } else if (flag == 2) {
          // do different implementation for flag 2
       } else {
          // do the other
       }
   }
}
```

**Edit:**
in kotlin it works with either override the property or override the getter

```
fun test_() {
        val theInterfaceImpl: ISomeKInterface = object : ISomeKInterface {

            //override val flag: Int = 2

            // the override the getter does the same as above override flag:Int = 2
            override val flag: Int
                get() {
                    val superFlag: Int = super.flag
                    println("+++ test override get(), flag:$superFlag, ret flag: 2")
                    return 2
                }
        // if no change to the default implementation this override is not required.
        override fun onProc(data: String) {
                println("+++ test override onProc(), flag: $flag default onProc(:$data)")
                super.onProc(data)
            }
        }
        val flag = theInterfaceImpl.flag
        println("+++ test current flag:$flag")
        theInterfaceImpl.onProc("eee888")
    }
```

But it does not compile if trying to use it in java.
In java it requires the `@Override public void onProc(String data)`, but it cannt call the super's default implementation - for the case that the default implementation of the `ISomeKInterface` is goog enough and does not need different implementation override.

```
    @Test
    public void test_() {

        ISomeKInterface theInterfaceImpl = new ISomeKInterface() {
            @Override
            public int getFlag() {
//                int superFlag = ISomeKInterface.super.getFlag(); //<== got error on ISomeKInterface.super.
//                System.out.println("+++ flag:"+superFlag+", ret flag: "+2);
                return 2;
            }

            @Override
            public void onProc(@NonNull String data) {

                // it is require the implement the onPro(data: String although it has the default implementation already)
                // but what if the super's default onProc() works fine, and does not need provide different implementation??? it seems cannot call the super.onProc here

                System.out.println("+++ test override onProc(:"+data);
                ISomeKInterface.super.onProc(data);  //<===
            }

        };
        int flag = theInterfaceImpl.getFlag();
        System.out.println("+++ current flag:"+flag);
        theInterfaceImpl.onProc("eee888");
    }

error: abstract method onProc(String) in ISomeKInterface cannot be accessed directly
                ISomeKInterface.super.onProc(data);  //<===
                                     ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I use kotlin interface in java , so easy

```
   public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ISomeKInterface iSomeKInterface = new ISomeKInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onProc() {
            }

            @Override
            public int getFlag() {
                return 2;
            }
        };
        System.out.println(iSomeKInterface.getFlag());
    }
}
```

Comment: if the default super.onProc() is the one to be called without modification, how to use this interface with default implementation in java?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the code `override val flag: Int = 2` not change the `flag` value  in `ISomeKInterface` ,and you can use `super.flag` get the the value which is 1.

further on，kotlin generate **get,set** function automatic， so if you want use in java, u need change the getFlag() function:

```
  ISomeKInterface anInterface = new ISomeKInterface() {
    @Override
    public void onProc(@NonNull Object data) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getFlag() {
        return 2;
    }
};
```

Comment: seems if trying to use in java code the super.flag or super. onProc() is not accessible.

Comment: yes u are right , i can use super.flag in kotlin can not in java.

Answer (score 0):

Default Method in Java 8:

```java
public interface Alarm {

    default String turnAlarmOn() {
        return "Turning the alarm on.";
    }
    
    default String turnAlarmOff() {
        return "Turning the alarm off.";
    }
}
```

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/java-static-default-methods